# Optimize sql query PHP Phalcon

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I Have this code:

```
            if(($banners = $this->app->cache5min->get($key_cache)) === NULL) {
            $find_items = array();
            $banners = $this->app->db->fetchAll("
SELECT  b.id,b.active, b.richmedia, b.rich_position, b.ip_limit,
        b.cookie_limit, b.cookie_interval, b.day_limit, b.limit_interval,
        b.frequency, b.close_btn, b.use_geo,
        bpl.s_x, bpl.s_y
    FROM  bs_items_places AS bp
    LEFT JOIN  bs_items AS b  ON b.id = bp.item_id
    LEFT JOIN  bs_places AS bpl  ON bpl.id = bp.place_id
    WHERE  b.active = 1
      AND  b.date_start < '".$dateNow."'
      AND  b.date_stop  > '".$dateNow."'
      AND  bpl.active = 1
      AND  bp.place_id = {$idpl}
      AND  (IF((time_from!='00:00:00' AND  time_to!='00:00:00'),
               (time_from<='".$dateTimeNow."'
           AND  time_to  >='".$dateTimeNow."'), 1)
           )
    GROUP BY  b.id
    ORDER BY  b.frequency DESC, b.day_limit DESC 
                                              ");
            foreach($banners AS $bnr) {
                $find_items[$bnr['id']] = $bnr;
            }
            $banners = $find_items;
            $this->app->cache5min->save($key_cache,$banners);
        }

    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($banners); exit;
    if(!$banners || !count($banners)) { return $this->getDefaultBanner($idpl,$x); }
```

When I remove first statement, my CPU is good, when I return first statement, my CPU 100% and this gives mysql proccess, how I Can Optimize select query?

Comment: First you would have to make it human-readable. But I can already tell, that you are not using prepared statements, which would mean that there is also a potential SQL injection vulnerability there

Comment: I need fix CPU load

Comment: Can't analyze the query without knowing which table each column is in -- in particular `time_from` and `time_to`.

Comment: "CPU load" is mostly caused by missing index or poorly written query.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to get rid of `LEFT`, unless you need it.  This may open up more optimization options.

This construct is essentially un-optimizable:

```
WHERE start < ...
  AND end   > ...
```

There is an "explode-implode" problem.  First, the number of rows explodes due to the `JOINs`, then it implodes do to the `GROUP BY`.  But... Meanwhile, there are no "aggregates" such as `COUNT()` or `SUM()`.  So this smells like a poorly formed query -- *Why* do you need to do the `GROUP BY`?  If you are getting 'duplicate' rows, then you have a worse problem -- what happens in the columns that are not duplicated?  You will get random values.  See what happens without the `GROUP BY`.

This composite index on `bp` *may* help:

```
INDEX(place_id, item_id)
```

Comment: @GodmanT - I gave you a couple of things to try.  I asked a couple of questions.